# Adding @And tag above existing clause in Cucmber step-def is disabling original Tag [JVM]

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I was trying to reuse few of the existing Step-def implementation, by adding `@And` tag on top of existing step-def implementation of `@Given` / `@When`

But its disabling existing link of `@Given` , if I put `@And` on top of it
& its not enabling link of `@And`, if I put it beneath `@Given`

Kindly advise, how to resolve this problem & reuse existing step-defs?

Many Thanks

```
@And("^User sends SMS \"([^\"]*)\"$")
@When("^User sends the command \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void User_sends_the_command(String sUserCommand) throws Throwable {
..
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse it for both And and When, the easiest is probably to call the same logic from two methods:

```
@When("^User sends the command \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void User_sends_the_command(String sUserCommand) throws Throwable {
  doLogic(sUserCommand);
}

@And("^User sends SMS \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void user_sends_sms(String sms) throws Throwable {
  doLogic(sms);
}
```

If you want to resuse an When (or And) in another When (or And), you can match it with regexp, something like:

```
@And("^User sends (?:SMS|the command) \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void User_sends_the_command(String sUserCommand) throws Throwable {
..
..
}
```

which will match both "User sends SMS abcd" and "User sends the command efgh"